# In API how to pass the credential encrypted manner

Tags: python, password-encryption

I am calling API via postman and giving all the input for respective API in Postman body in JSON format. Because of that credential details are visible in body and its not safe. how to handle this credential encryption scenario?

JSOM input:

> {"req_type":"API","src_db_type":"MYSQL","src_db_schemaname":"testdb","src_db_connection":"{"connection":{"host":"localhost", "username":"XXXXXX", "password":"XXXX","port":"3306","db":"testdb","auth_plugin":"mysql_native_password"}}"

Expectation is credential should not reflect while calling API.

Comment: As long as the connection is https, body is not visible to anyone but sender and the target. You could also use headers (in https they are also encrypted) - I actually prefer headers because they're easier to check as you don't need to parse body and you can always quickly deny access based on lack of needed header (e.g. in AWS API Gateway - when such preliminary check fails, they don't bill you for usage, so spam requests won't incur costs for you)

Answer (score -3):

To handle the scenario of encrypting credentials in the API request, you can follow these steps:

Use HTTPS: Make sure you are making the API request over HTTPS instead of HTTP. This ensures that the communication between your client (Postman) and the server is encrypted.

Separate Configuration: Instead of sending the credentials directly in the API request body, store them in a separate configuration file or environment variables on the server. This way, you can avoid including sensitive information in the API payload.

Authentication: Implement a secure authentication mechanism for your API. Use techniques such as token-based authentication or OAuth, where the client obtains an access token after providing valid credentials. This way, the actual credentials are not sent with every request.

Use Credential Management Systems: Consider using a credential management system or secret management tool, such as HashiCorp Vault or AWS Secrets Manager. These tools allow you to securely store and retrieve sensitive information like passwords, API keys, and other credentials.

Hash and Encrypt: If you still need to include credentials in the API payload, you can hash and encrypt the sensitive data before sending it. On the server side, you can then decrypt and verify the credentials. However, note that this approach requires additional implementation and security measures to handle encryption keys securely.

this is a simplified example, and it's important to use a well-established encryption library and follow best practices for key management in a production environment.

```
import base64
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

# Generate a encryption key
def generate_key():
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    return key

# Encrypt the credentials
def encrypt_credentials(plain_text, key):
    cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
    cipher_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(plain_text.encode())
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(cipher_text).decode()

# Decrypt the credentials
def decrypt_credentials(cipher_text, key):
    cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
    cipher_text = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(cipher_text)
    plain_text = cipher_suite.decrypt(cipher_text).decode()
    return plain_text

# Example usage
key = generate_key()
credentials = '{"username": "myuser", "password": "mypassword"}'

# Encrypt the credentials
encrypted_credentials = encrypt_credentials(credentials, key)
print('Encrypted credentials:', encrypted_credentials)

# Decrypt the credentials
decrypted_credentials = decrypt_credentials(encrypted_credentials, key)
print('Decrypted credentials:', decrypted_credentials)
```

Comment: ChatGPT is not allowed, please put some effort into making your answers.

Comment: The code i provided is coded by my self used in one of my project as for theory for explaning it good i googled it. and for techniques like Hasing and saving your password in environment variable or using seprate config for that is common knowledge i don't need to use GPT for that. :)

Comment: @Ahtess_Khan with that comment you just proved it was chatgpt - the style used in comment isn't even close to the style in the answer. The only part that matches the style is the paragraph just before the code.

Comment: @h4z3 Sir/Ma'am  I am not here to debate weather i used it or not beacause its pointless to tell someone who has already made his/her mind :) . I would be happy if it helps the person asking the question in any way.So Have a nice day.

Comment: As mentioned by others here, your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). While you say that you are trying to be helpful, the community here strongly believes that AI-generated answers are generally *not* helpful.  As a result [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.